# Upload File via Excel AddOn

Tags: .net, file-upload, ms-office, uac, add-on

I need to develop a Add on for Excel (2003 and greater), it must upload the excel file when click the Save Button (with the event Application_DocumentBeforeSave). 
My question is how can I do that?

I try with Net.WebClient UploadFile and runs OK on WinXP but doesnt work on Windows Vista and Windows 7, may be the UAC or some security model is stoping the action, I dont know.

The file must be uploaded via http and https.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to create a Java Web Service and call it using C# webervice reference. convert the doc to a byte stream and the java web service make the rest of the logic.